# How to specify the format of pandas.to_datetime('now')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I alter/specify the output of the following call?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('now')
```

Gives me e.g.

```
Timestamp('2018-05-09 09:56:36')
```

.to_datetime has a format parameter, but

```
pd.to_datetime('now', format='%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
```

but this gives me a

```
ValueError: time data 'now' does not match format '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S' (match)
```

I also tried

```
pd.to_datetime('now').dt_strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
```

but I end up with

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt_strftime'
```

How can achieve an output `'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'` here?

I am using Python 3.6.4 and Pandas 0.22.0.

Comment: You can't change the display format for datetimes, you can only do this by converting to a string so `pd.to_datetime('now').strftime( '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S' )` but this defeats the point of having datetimes. Currently pandas does not have an option to change the way that datetimes are displayed in the output

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate of an identical question. The answer there won't help, though, for reasons explained by @EdChum.

Comment: @EdChum Thank you for explaining this.

Comment: @jpp Well, it is similar, but still I think somewhat different as I use 'now' here, i.e. and ad hoc generated timestamp.